# Lambda does not override an interface method from a separate file

Tags: java, lambda, interface

1. When the functional interface is in the same file where lambda overrides it, it compiles fine.

```
package test.test;
public class Base {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface1 a = n -> System.out.println(2*n);
    }
}
interface Interface1 { 
    void multiplyByTwo(int x); 
}
```

2. When the functional interface is in a separate file and Base class implements it, it fails to compile with `Base is not abstract and does not override abstract method multiplyByFour(int) in Interface3` error.

```
package test.test;
public class Base implements Interface3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interface3 b = n -> System.out.println(4*n);
    }
}
```

```
package test.test;
public interface Interface3 { 
    void multiplyByFour(int x); 
}
```

3. Is here something wrong? Why does lambda not override the method in the second case?

Comment: you don't need to implement it to use

Comment: The class `Base` doesn't need to implement the interface that a lambda in that class matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example has:

```
public class Base {
```

which does not implement `Interface1`

However, your second example has:

```
public class Base implements Interface3 {
```

which DOES implement `Interface3`

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but this is intended behaviour:

### Interfaces

When a class implements an `interface`, you must implement all of the methods into the class

For example:

```
public interface IFoo {
    void bar();
}
```

and class:

```
public class FooImpl implements IFoo {
    // must implement bar method in IFoo
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("I did something");
    }

}
```

Having a lambda in the main method does not constitute implementing interface methods.

### Fix?

Just delete `implements Interface3`, you don't need to implement the interface in your class to be able to use it.